# Image Replacment with CSS and media query

Tags: html, image, css, media-queries

I have an image and I want to switch it's css according to screen size aka Media queries. Right now, the code looks something like this

`<img src="image.jpg" widht="20" height="20" alt="Logo"/>`

Of course it has width and height written in inline.

In my CSS, I want to change the size of the image. For example, On the full screen, I want the image to show its full width, and on mobile screen I want to show the `width of 200px`. How can I achieve this by CSS and media queries.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Its really simple just specify the type of media you want to target and the breakpoints. for example.

FOR DESKTOP

```
img { width:100%; height:auto }
```

FOR MOBILE

```
@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
    img { width:100%; max-width:200px; height:auto; }
}
```

Comment: Do I have to take width and height from inline and put it in the css instead?

Comment: no, the inline stuff can remain, it basically says "this is my default ratio" the css will scale up the image from there. Those attributes aren't mandatory but they are good practice. :)

Comment: It's not working. The mobile size works fine, but desktop is not changing. I am actually entering PX value rather then 100%. The file is huge on 100%. hence I need to condense it down.

Comment: Sorry, I think i misunderstood part of the question. Do you mean to keep the default image size for desktop and scale to 200px wide on mobile? If so I've created a fiddle with the a possible solution. Let me know if this is what you meant :) http://jsfiddle.net/cK3ay/1/

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. Thanks.